What would you call these interior balconies? Interior balconies or just the second/third/etc. story? (AmE)
I am talking about those balcony structures that often partly jut out over the story below them. For example, in the atrium of a mall or in a fancy mansion.


In the first picture, that balcony wraps completely around and protrudes over the first story of the mansion and in the second picture, the balconies stick out over the stories below them.

No, not balconies. Perhaps galleries.

Haven't seen that article before. But if the first one is a mezzanine then what's the second?

You're quite interested in this kind of architectural structure, aren't you?  What is your use for this term?  This is important because it changes the answer.  For example in the photo of the shopping mall, a shopper would not need to refer to the structure but might need to refer to the location.  A shopper would not need a word for this type of balcony.  But an architect might...  That means that the word used might be considered technical.  So we need your help to explain how you would use the word.  What is the story?

Please also add the source of your photographs.  This is also very important.  Because it lets us see the research.  We can assume you have read the web page you found these on.  If you didn't get the first one from Wikipedia, where did you see it?

A balcony has two end points. That style is called a balustrade. Those two pictures are very different. The first is a colonnaded hallway opening onto a balustraded  stairway. The second is an open second and third floor in a mall.  mezzanines are between floors. Those are not that.

The second one looks like: a double racetrack format.  https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-design-shopping-mall-hussam-raouf From having one central circulation or corridor with two anchor stores at either end (what we call the dumbbell format) to the double racetrack format, allowing customers to flow around the mall in a loop that ends at its starting point, there are a variety of mall layouts that can be used.

@Lambie A balustrade is the railing on the edge - as long as it's formed of balusters, which it more often isn't (first picture yes, second picture no). It does not refer to the floor behind that railing.

@Divizna You have got to be kidding me. You are telling me the definition? The stairway handrail does have a balustrade. . I never said it referred to the floor. I said: it is a colonnaded hallway opening onto a balustraded stairway. Of course, the entire handrail along hallway and down the stairs are balustraded, i.e. have balusters.

@ishtar not a mezzanine, because they are on the same level as the upper floors. The photo you linked is of a split level.

@James K. My goal is to become a conference interpreter. As a conference interpreter, I need to have an extensive active vocabulary at my fingertips because this profession entails talking about a wide range of complex topics ranging from medical subjects all the way to architectural subjects.

Please also add the source of your photographs. This is also very important. Because it lets us see the research. We can assume you have read the web page you found these on. If you didn't get the first one from Wikipedia, where did you see it?

Re being a conference interpreter.  I suggest you get some significant experience living in a country where English is the native language.  At the moment your attitude is too inflexible to be a successful interpreter. Living and working in a completely English environment might help you to free yourself of this rigidity of thought. Of course immigration laws etc make that difficult and costly so this isn't an easy goal to achieve.

I don't think that my attitude toward the way the language is used is too rigid. I know that language is a flexible tool used for communication but and that native speakers don't adhere to rules 90% of the time, particularly in informal contexts, so I know that I don't have to be perfect in informal conversations either. However, conference interpreting requires a somewhat pedantic attitude toward the use of a language as even the slightest misunderstanding can have serious ramifications, so in formal contexts, conference interpreters are expected to have an inflexible attitude.

Related: What do you call the upper areas of a theater?

Are you specifically referring to one that protrudes beyond a lower level?

Fyi, I am a conference interpreter as well as being a consecutive interpreter.  When one is scheduled for a properly organized conference, the organizers supply documentation, no interpreter is expected to jump into any field without those two things and their own research on a topic. We don't sit around all day feeding our brain with all sorts of arcana.

You might find this answer on ELL useful for your purposes. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/456438/when-is-a-phrase-idiomatic/456445#456445 Also, fyi, I have done a lot of written translation in architecture and building, so you might want to reread my comments above. Generally, hallways with columns are said to be colonnaded or have colonnades (columns).

Conference interpreters are not "inflexible". Conferences generally have prepared statements or presentations whereas consecutive does not.  What is expected in CI is grammaticality. semantic coherence and accuracy. Also, flexibility. If you can't think how to say it one way, you have to be able to deliver the same meaning another way.  In some ways, CI is easier than consecutive which is much trickier. In consecutive, you have to match the spoken language of the speaker. Much harder in fact.

It's funny but I gave you all sorts of relevant information, and you don't respond? Oh, in CI with speeches, the interpreter is often given advance copies and can do a sort of sight translation of the speeches/presentations.

Why do you get stuff from Wikipedia and then ask about it AGAIN here? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mezzanine They claim those are mezzanines as they do not count as full floors. So be it. Sometimes, you can't really tell without entering a building. The Canadian one does not actually show as a mezzazine, in the picture. We cannot tell. Also, you need to provide links and not take random pictures off the internet like that. It's not fair to the photographers.

There isn't a clear distinction, other than what building codes might say, but here are some definitions.
A balcony is a space projecting from the wall of a building (Wikipedia), internally or externally. An indoor balcony or interior balcony is a balcony that is internal to a property, looking down from a high floor to a lower one. A balcony can be supported on vertical pillars or cantilevered (sticking out from the wall without additional support below). The balustrade is the horizontal barrier that stops you falling off the edge.
A mezzanine is a (generally low-ceilinged) partial floor covering some but not all of the total area below and usually with some kind of interior balcony looking down. (Wikipedia). Commonly it is located between the first two proper floors, i.e. in the US floor numbering between first and second floor, but it can be anywhere and you can have multiple.
It contrasts with a structural floor, which is a floor that is an integral part of a building; mezzanines can be installed later or even moved around (particularly in industrial contexts). However, there is not necessarily a clear difference except in the arbitrary limits used in building codes or other documents, which may vary from place to place: a mezzanine typically doesn't count as a floor for some purposes, and therefore will have an effect on adherence to building codes, maybe property taxation, rental agreements, etc. Naming may also be done by building owners or managers for other reasons: "mezzanine" may sound classier but "second floor" makes it easier to navigate.
Gallery has several meanings, but one is a covered space that is open at one side, often long and thin and running along a wall. (Britannica). The term is often used in theatres where you have a higher seating or standing area running around the wall above the main space (stalls or atrium) - Wikipedia). In general use, the difference between a balcony and a gallery isn't hard and fast, but a gallery will tend to be longer.
An atrium is a large space covering multiple stories in a building. (Designing Buildings wiki) Often they are surrounded by galleries with balustrades, although there may be internal windows or some other design element. Technically the term refers to the space, but is often used for the entire structure with floor, galleries, stairs/escalators/lifts, etc. They are common in modern office buildings where a multi-floor atrium provides a grand entry space, and breaking up floors in a structure where everything is located around the edge of the building (like most malls).
A stair well is a space in a building for stairs, while a stairway is the structure of steps which can include 180 degree bends, curves or other feature. An escalator well or escalator well-way is a space for escalators.
So nomenclature will depend on the precise purpose of the different structural elements, and what the architect, building owner, or manager chooses to emphasise.

Yes, sure, atrium for the mall one. But the other shows a stairway, not a stairwell, which is usually an enclose space within a building accessed via a door. A mezzanine is an intermediate floor coming between two regular floors. Those pictures do not show one.

Depending on where you live, you could say third floor or Level 3, though in American English, the first one is used more than the second. Story isn't used much in terms of what floor or level something or someone is on. Rather, it is used as an adjective noun, such as "three-story building".
If it was a balcony in between, people call that a mezzanine.

Thanks but I still don't know what those are called.
